# Visual Studio "has encountered an unexpected error." after trying to compile my code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

[image: Screen shot]

After trying to compile my code, a simple error message appears: "Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error."

Im using Visual Studio Community 2019.

I know very little about coding, so go easy on me. Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main() {
    float counter = 1, sum = 0;
    int n;

    printf("Count until n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    do {
        sum = sum + counter;
        counter = counter + 2;
    } while (counter < n);

    printf("Sum=%4.2f", sum);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I was wrong to include this code, as it appears, with ANY CODE, the same thing happens, which leads me to believe that my PC is the problem, not the code

Comment: Other than the missing return type on `main` mentioned above, the code looks pretty good. Certainly nothing that should crash the IDE. I'm afraid you are unlikely to get a good answer here.

Comment: there are two valid signatures for function: `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`.  Notice they both have a return type of `int`

Comment: @user3629249: Those are the strictly conforming signatures for `main`. Implementations may, and do, define others that are conforming but not strictly conforming.

Comment: Use another machine, this one has cooties.

Comment: regarding: `} while (counter < n);`  This is comparing a `float` to an `int`  This requires an implicit conversion that is not (usually) a good idea.  Suggest changing `int n;`  to `float n;`  and changing `scanf("%d", &n);`  To `scanf("%f", &n);`  Note should always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversions'  In the current scenario,  any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: OT: the literals 0, 1, 2 are integer literals.  Should use `float` literals, similar to: `1.0f` `0.0f` and `2.0f`

Comment: Some mentioned changing n to float, I've tried, doesn't help with the issue, my teacher actually suggested that I set n to int, and I fully knowing that it wont change anything, did as she asked, as for the rest, yea I understood nothing :/  thank you for your help

Comment: @HansPassant can you explain, i didnt understand what you were trying to say

Comment: “Cooties” are literally lice (as may infest in human hair}, but the word is rarely used in that sense. It is used colloquially to mean some nonspecific icky presence, like germs. The meaning is something is wrong with your computer. It could be as simple as a file permissions problem or a missing directory. Regardless, Stack Overflow is not the place to diagnose it. Perhaps your school has some technical support services.

Comment: Using Visual Studio is always an unexpected error. Just kidding, I have no idea other than that your installation of Visual Studio is erroneous. You might like to de- and re-install it. I had to use Visual Studio too many times, and it was every time an unpleasant experience. If you don't *have to* use it, try any other compiler and IDE.